# Creating a pandas dataframe from a JSON request

Tags: python, json, pandas, flask

I am trying to create a machine Learning application with Flask. I have created a POST API route that will take the data and transform it into a pandas dataframe. Here is the Flask code that calls the python function to transform the data.

```
from flask import Flask, abort, request
import json
import mlFlask as ml
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def test():
    if not request.json:
        abort(400)
    print type(request.json)
    result = ml.classification(request.json)
    return json.dumps(result)
```

This is the file that contains the helper function.

```
def jsonToDataFrame(data):
    print type(data)
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data,orient='columns')
```

But I am getting an import error. Also, when I print the type of data is dict so I don't know why it would cause an issue. It works when I orient the dataframe based on index but it doesn't work based on column.

> ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Here is the body of the request in JSON format.

```
{
"updatedDate":"2012-09-30T23:51:45.778Z",
"createdDate":"2012-09-30T23:51:45.778Z",
"date":"2012-06-30T00:00:00.000Z",
"name":"Mad Max",
"Type":"SBC",
"Org":"Private",
"month":"Feb"
}
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Why are you not just using `pandas.read_json()`? See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).